# Why does np.array([4, 3, 0]) + np.array([0, 2, 2]) give an output of array([4,5,2])

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why does `np.array([4, 3, 0]) + np.array([0, 2, 2])` give an output of `array([4,5,2])`

Can anyone explain it to me in detail ?

Comment: Elementwisse addition. What else did you expect?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem (nitpicking, but) more semantically, vector addition. Numpy's arrays were originally designed for numerical computing with the arrays and matrices representing mathematical vectors and matrices.

Comment: (double nitpicking) Mathematical `vector addition` is defined without direct reference to a coordinate system.  If the vectors are represented as cartesian coordinates, then vector addition can be performed by summing corresponding components, i.e. `elementwise`.  The basic object in numpy is a multidimensional array.  The mapping to vector and matrix as used in math, physics or engineering is not exact.

Comment: @hpaulj TIL, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal vector addition. You just add every element in a vector to the corresponding element in the other vector.

```
 [4, 3, 0]
+[0, 2, 2]
___________
=[4, 5, 2]
```

Note: if the result of a vector addition is >9, the extra digit does not overflow to the next item in the vector. E.g.

```
 [4, 9, 0]
+[0, 2, 2]
___________
=[4,11, 2]
```

If you found this answer useful I recommend picking up linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

It's adding each element in the numpy array with the element at the same index in the other numpy array.

```
4 + 0 = 0
3 + 2 = 5
0 + 2 = 2
```

Comment: you shouldn't say list, because adding `list` objects is concatenating them: `[1]+[2]` gives `[1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to append arrays you can use:

```
np.append(np.array([4, 3, 0]), np.array([0, 2, 2]))
```